SAS Enterprise Guide - How to keep Process Flow always visible
I am using SAS EG 8.3
When I run a query - it automatically opens results in a new tab in the same window my Process Flow is. Which is not good for me because the new tab hides the Process Flow window.
At my previous job, I was used to work in a way that the screen is split horizontally into two windows:
In the above window I always see the whole Process flow. it is important to me that the Process flow  always stays visible on top.
In the window below I want to see each time the outputs of a query I run. Each run - different results below. Also, when I double click on any table in the process flow, I want it to show that data table's preview in the window below.
I played a bit with options, I managed to horizontally split the window, but it still replaces the Process flow view each time I double click a table.
How to achieve this?
Thanks

